# How to disable bounce when dragging content over scroll limit in Windows 8 app?

Tags: css, windows-8

I'm building a Windows 8 app, and need to disable the over-dragging / bounce-back effect that occurs when a user drags scrollable content over its parent's scroll limit.  I thought I might be able to use [some CSS properties here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453816.aspx), but none of them seemed to allow me to do that.  Any suggestions?

Comment: are you developing it native or with phonegap?

Comment: Developing with HTML5 + WinJS

Answer (score -1):

```
body{overflow:hidden}
```

will fix the boucing issue

Comment: Then how to scroll the content